# return bool in switch case

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

I am trying switch case and inheritance in C++ and found some problems/ warnings.

For example I have an abstract basic class Field:

```
Field.h

class Field{
  private:
  FieldType type_;

  public:
  enum FieldType
  {
    GRASS,WATER,STREET,HOME,TOWNHALL
  };
virtual bool checkIsBuildable(Fieldtype type);
```

Now I get warnings in subclasses Buildings.cpp and Properties.cpp:

```
  warning enumeration value GRASS,WATER,STREET bit handled in switch
```

Since it is a bool i just can return false or true in default and the method wont work propely or?
I just want to check for example Home and Townhall in Buildings.cpp and Grass, Water and street in Properties.

```
Buildings.cpp

bool Buildings::isBuildable(Field::FieldType type)
{    
   switch(type)
  {
    case Field::HOME:
      return true;
    case Field::TOWNHALL:
      return false;
  }
}

Properties.cpp

 bool Properties::isBuildable(Field::FieldType type)
{    
   switch(type)
  {
    case Field::GRASS:
      return true;
    case Field::WATER:
      return false;
    case Field::STREET:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to handle *all* the cases. What if the type *isn't* any of the one you list in the `switch`? What do you return then? Add a `default` case.

Comment: Apart from the missing default: you don't need to repeat identical code in every case, you can just do: `case X: caseY: commonXYCode(); break;`

Comment: The warning is that your `switch` doesn't cover all the values in your `enum`. The warning is suggesting to add a `default` case so it is clear that all other cases not explicitly mentioned are handled.

Comment: And if you logically won't have a `default` case, because the caller already should have arranged for that, then a `throw std::invalid_argument` makes sense for the default case.

Comment: For a decision this simple I wouldn't use a `switch` statement. `return type == HOME || type == TOWNHALL;`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `default`: `return true`; or `return false`; in this context;

```
bool Properties::isBuildable(Field::FieldType type)
{    
   switch(type)
  {
    case Field::GRASS:
      return true;
    case Field::WATER:
      return false;
    case Field::STREET:
      return false;
    default:
      return false;

  }
}
```

Or just add return out of switch scope:

```
bool Properties::isBuildable(Field::FieldType type)
{    
   switch(type)
  {
    case Field::GRASS:
      return true;
    case Field::WATER:
      return false;
    case Field::STREET:
      return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Because if your type won't be equal to one of the values from case then function won't return any value, you need to fix it with a help of methods shown above.

Comment: Ahh true, since the virtual methode will just called themself in the right class. Thanks alot !

Comment: you could then delete a collection of lines so that you have `case Field::Grass:  case Field::Concrete: return true;  default: return false;`